# How do I show the user ID?

Tags: views

I have a website where some holistic operators work together. I have created an *Operator-Article* node for every operator.

I also created a blog view to show the articles of each single operator.
This view uses the user ID of the article author.

I also created a view to show a list of operators in a table showing:

- Photo
- Name (link to curriculum page)
- A link to the articles created by the user, which links to the blog view

To create the links to the blog view I used:

- An hidden field (*Created by*) with the Entity ID formatter to get the user ID
- A field using the following re-writing results:
  Text: "Read its articles"
  Link path: `/blog/{{ uid }}`

If I log in, the view works correctly, giving for example a link like 
site/blog/75. If I am not logged-in, `{{ uid }}` is not rendered, and the link becomes site/blog/.

To test the view, I show the *Created by* fieldm and when I login I see the UID (for example 75).

> [image: screenshot]

If I am not logged-in, I don't see anything.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I solve this problem, and use `{{ uid }}` even when I'm not logged-in?